# UITableView Sections are not scrolling to top after ContentInset set

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I created a UITableView with ContentInset of 75.

In `UITableView`, I set a section view with height 30

Now when I scroll the `UITableView`, section is fixed at 75, not scrolls along with table cells, How can I make it scroll beyond the `contentInset` along with table cells

Is there any built-in property of `UITableView` to achieve this or any custom solution for this?

Comment: self.tableView.style = UITableViewStyleGrouped. write this line in ViewDidLoad method. May this help you!

Comment: Thanks, it gives error `Cannot assign to property: 'style' is a get-only property` any idea about this

Comment: @yagneshdobariya i set it in the initialization of tableview `tableview = UITableView(CGRectZero, style: .Grouped);`, then it works thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your tableview's style form plain to group .

[image]